# Merge columns and create new column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns:

1. Product name
2. Number of product sold in New York (let's say 100)
3. Number of product sold in California (let's say 50)

Looks like this:

```
Product     New York    California
Widget01    100         50
```

I want to reshape the frame using the two location columns to create a new column like this:

```
Product     Location      Total Sold
Widget01    New York      100
Widget01    California    50
```

How does one achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.melt()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) -

```
pd.melt(df,id_vars='Product', var_name='Location',value_name='Total Sold')
```

Demo -

```
In [72]: df
Out[72]:
    Product  New York  California
0  Widget01       100          50

In [73]: pd.melt(df,id_vars='Product', var_name='Location',value_name='Total Sold')
Out[73]:
    Product    Location  Total Sold
0  Widget01    New York         100
1  Widget01  California          50
```

Comment: I agree with `pd.melt`, but I don't understand your `value_vars`.  Why not simply `pd.melt(df, id_vars="Product", var_name="Location", value_name="Total Sold")`?

Comment: Yea, you are right fixed it, just noticed that if its not set, it takes all columns not specified as id_vars. Thank you.